# Using search function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have spent hours trying to think of a solution to this so I give us and ask for help!!

I have different products (in cells A2 to A10) which are different terms. The description in the cell is 'Bake 5 year award' or it could be 'Style 3 year award'.

I need to use the search function to determine whether of not it is a 3 or 5 year product and then based on that, I need it to copy the term '3 year' or '5 year' to another workbook i.e. not copy over the other words in the description e.g Bake.

Comment: I normally add a help column to the worksheet and then filter on the help column.  In your case the helper column would contain "2 year", "3 year", "5 year".  Here is a formula that you can add to the helper column to get the year number : =TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND("year",A1)  +4 - FIND(" ",A1)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this UDF based on regular expression

```
Function findYear(str As String) As String
    Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"):reg.Pattern = "\d+ year"
    Set matches = reg.Execute(str): findYear = matches(0).Value
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this solution may meet your expectations.

You can create function that will extract numer for your description:

```
Function ExtractDigits(s As String) As String
Dim retval As String    
Dim i As Integer

retval = ""

For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
        retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
    End If
Next

ExtractDigits = retval
End Function
```

You can use this function to put required data into other sheet.

```
If ExtractDigits(Worksheet("Source").Cells(1,2) = 1 Then
   Worksheet("OtherSheet").Cells(1,1) = ExtractDigits(Worksheet("Source").Cells(1,2) + " year"
Else
   Worksheet("OtherSheet").Cells(1,1) = ExtractDigits(Worksheet("Source").Cells(1,2) + " years"
End
```